# Android change button background on activity start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have two drawable files defined:
button_neutral.xml

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/app_dark_grey"/>
</shape>
```

calendar_button_friends .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item> 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/app_yellow"/> 
        </shape>
    </item>   
    <item android:bottom="5dp" >  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
            <solid android:color="@color/app_dark_grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>    
</layer-list>
```

As can be seen, the button_neutral is just a solid dark grey bground, and the button selected is the grey bground with a yellow line at the bottom.

Depending on how the activity is started, I may want to apply the selected bground to a button on the screen - so examining the intent passed to the activity I attempt to set the background button as so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_calendar, null);
        int filter = extras.getInt("CALENDAR_FILTER");
        switch (filter) {
        case Constants.CALENDAR_SOCIAL_FILTER : 
            Button btn = ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_filter_social));
            System.out.println("XXXXX " + btn.getBackground().toString());
            btn.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.calendar_button_friends );
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            System.out.println("XXXXX " + btn.getBackground().toString());
            break;
        case Constants.CALENDAR_FAMILY_FILTER : 
            ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_filter_family)).setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.calendar_button_family);
            break;
        case Constants.CALENDAR_WORK_FILTER : 
            ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_filter_work)).setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.calendar_button_work);
            break;
        case Constants.CALENDAR_ALL_FILTER : 
            ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_filter_all)).setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.calendar_button_all);
            break;
        }
    }

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
}
```

All the intent, switch works fine - but I cannot get the change in button background to show up. I have applied the drawable explicitly in the layout xml to make sure and that works fine, but I cannot get the button bground to be set in the onCreate of the activity being loaded.

I have also tried calling `invalidate()` as a long shot, and also tried just using `btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you please show the rest of the code, below the first case block?

Comment: @androiddeveloper updated code to include entire onCreate()  - I tried adding the super call before and after the UI change to see if it made a difference, but no joy.

Comment: hmm, any details from whoverer downvoted the question two years later? Just curious..

Comment: I have no idea. It doesn't say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see multiple weird things here:

1. you forgot to use the view that you've inflated - use **setContentView(view);**
2. now that i think about it, why do you inflate a view in the first place, instead of using:

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
   ```

   ?
3. you handle a different button to set the background on each case of the switch-case. is it on purpose?
4. the "**super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );**" should be the first line of the code .
5. on the first case, you call "**setBackgroundResource**" and right after that "**setBackgroundColor**" . the second call will cancel the previous one.

Comment: 1) Sorry, I actually extend another custom class (not just Activity) and that calls SetContentView();  2) YES!!! This was the problem - I stopped inflating the view and just used the activity view and it started working;  3) Yep, that was intentional  4) Cool -as mentioned that was just my trial and error!  5) Yes, again, that was just me getting desperate and ruling out that it was anything specific about my drawable resource so just set a colour to test it.  Thanks though!

Comment: I would actually upvote this twice if i could - this also solved an issue I hadn't really thought about with a custom font not working - same reason.

Comment: about custom font, you might want to create a custom textView so that all such instances will use the same memory that was allocated for the font (and it will reduce the time to load it over and over again).

Comment: oh and about the upvotes, thanks. you are actually the one who made my score above 15K . :)